# Output as a sequence with three steps in household power consumption example in Keras

Tags: python, sequence, keras

The below is a famous example in LSTM in time series domain "[household power consumption](https://github.com/Vict0rSch/deep_learning/blob/master/keras/recurrent/recurrent_keras_power.py)" in Keras. It predicts `the fifth` value based on the `49` time steps before that. My question is that how to change this code such a way that it can predict the next three steps rather than just one step. In other words, I want to give 49 time steps and get the three time steps as output.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import csv
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
np.random.seed(1234)


def data_power_consumption(path_to_dataset,
                           sequence_length=50,
                           ratio=1.0):

    max_values = ratio * 2049280

    with open(path_to_dataset) as f:
        data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
        power = []
        nb_of_values = 0
        for line in data:
            try:
                power.append(float(line[2]))
                nb_of_values += 1
            except ValueError:
                pass
            # 2049280.0 is the total number of valid values, i.e. ratio = 1.0
            if nb_of_values >= max_values:
                break

    print "Data loaded from csv. Formatting..."

    result = []
    for index in range(len(power) - sequence_length):
        result.append(power[index: index + sequence_length])
    result = np.array(result)  # shape (2049230, 50)

    result_mean = result.mean()
    result -= result_mean
    print "Shift : ", result_mean
    print "Data  : ", result.shape

    row = int(round(0.9 * result.shape[0]))
    train = result[:row, :]
    np.random.shuffle(train)
    X_train = train[:, :-1]
    y_train = train[:, -1]
    X_test = result[row:, :-1]
    y_test = result[row:, -1]

    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

    return [X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test]


def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    layers = [1, 50, 100, 1]

    model.add(LSTM(
        layers[1],
        input_shape=(None, layers[0]),
        return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(
        layers[2],
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(
        layers[3]))
    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    start = time.time()
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
    print "Compilation Time : ", time.time() - start
    return model


def run_network(model=None, data=None):
    global_start_time = time.time()
    epochs = 1
    ratio = 0.5
    sequence_length = 50
    path_to_dataset = 'household_power_consumption.txt'

    if data is None:
        print 'Loading data... '
        X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = data_power_consumption(
            path_to_dataset, sequence_length, ratio)
    else:
        X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = data

    print '\nData Loaded. Compiling...\n'

    if model is None:
        model = build_model()

    try:
        model.fit(
            X_train, y_train,
            batch_size=512, nb_epoch=epochs, validation_split=0.05)
        predicted = model.predict(X_test)
        predicted = np.reshape(predicted, (predicted.size,))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Training duration (s) : ', time.time() - global_start_time
        return model, y_test, 0

    try:
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(y_test[:100])
        plt.plot(predicted[:100])
        plt.show()
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
    print 'Training duration (s) : ', time.time() - global_start_time

    return model, y_test, predicted


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_network()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would solve your issue:

```
def predict_sequences_multiple(model, data, window_size, prediction_len):
    #Predict sequence of 50 steps before shifting prediction run forward by 50 steps
    prediction_seqs = []
    for i in range(int(len(data)/prediction_len)):
        curr_frame = data[i*prediction_len]
        predicted = []
        for j in range(prediction_len):
            predicted.append(model.predict(curr_frame[newaxis,:,:])[0,0])
            curr_frame = curr_frame[1:]
            curr_frame = np.insert(curr_frame, [window_size-1], predicted[-1], axis=0)
        prediction_seqs.append(predicted)
    return prediction_seqs
```